# c++ ffmpeg access violation

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

What's wrong in this code? It is breaking (access violation) at av_find_stream_info. While debugging, ctx->filename is "3" instead of "1.MP3": first 4 chars are omitted, checked for other files too, same result.

```
av_register_all();
AVFormatContext *ctx=0;
ctx=avformat_alloc_context();
avformat_open_input(&ctx,"1.MP3",0,0);
av_find_stream_info(ctx);
int istream;
for(int i=0;i<ctx->nb_streams;i++){
if(ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO){
        istream=i;
        break;
}
```

Comment: You'll never be able to debug code that contains no error checking. What's the return value from `avformat_open_input`?

Comment: avformat_open_input returns -2.

Answer (score 4):

`avformat_open_input` is failing.

Use [`av_strerror`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/error_8c.html#5792b4a2d18d7d9cb0efbcfc335dce24) to find out why `avformat_open_input` is failing.  A negative value returned by `avformat_open_input` indicates an error condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a bug -- it is calling `av_find_stream_info` even if `avformat_open_input` fails.

`-2` is probably `-ENOENT` -- no such file or directory. Perhaps you're in the wrong directory. Perhaps the file's name is `1.mp3`, not `1.MP3`, and your filesystem is case-sensitive.

But you can't debug code that doesn't check for errors.

Comment: After putting the full path "F:\\1.mp3", avformat_open_input is returning 0 (success), but at the same time ctx->filename is ".mp3", first 4 characters trimmed.

Comment: You're asking me to debug code I can't see. There's no way to do that.

Comment: Problem is the avformatcontext has all the wrong info (it shows millions of streams). Is there any other way to read a single stream instead of using aformat, using avcodec only? I know the file has a single audio stream.

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you're trying to do. Are you trying to decode the audio stream? It's not clear what problem you're having. You are now opening the file successfully. Your issue with reading the filename is probably just that you're reading it out wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right path. You've now got the file open, so keep going.

Comment: As I said, though the return values are zero's, the structure AVFormatContext is not populated correctly, so I am not opening the file successfully..

Comment: Again, you're asking me to debug code I can't see. Paste the code that shows the error, including how you extracted the incorrect values from the structure. Just keep fixing the bugs. That's how programming works.